# Dumping memory of a function

Tags: c++, hex, arrays, function-pointers, dump

I would like to dump a functions memory (void) to a byte array (`unsinged char[]`). Aftwerwards, a dummy function shall be pointed to the byte array and the dummy function shall be executed.

The function I want to dump:

```
void CallMessageBoxExA()
{
    message = "ManualMessageBoxExA";
    caption = "Caption";
    pAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"User32.dll"), "MessageBoxExA");

    __asm // Call MessageBoxA
    {
        push dword ptr 0 //--- push languageID: 0
        push dword ptr 0 //--- push style: 0
        push dword ptr caption //--- push DWORD parameter (caption)
        push dword ptr message //--- push DWORD parameter (message)
        push dword ptr 0 //--- push hOwner: 0
        mov eax, pAddr
        call eax //-- call address of the function, which is currently in EAX
    }
}
```

Dumping the memory:

```
string DumpMemory(void *pAddress, int maxLength)
{
    string result = "";
    const unsigned char * p = reinterpret_cast< const unsigned char *>(pAddress);
    cout << "Memory location: 0x" << hex << (unsigned int)p << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
        string code = "";
        stringstream ss;
        ss << hex << int(p[i]);
        ss >> code;
        result += code;
    }
    return result;
}
```

When looking at the memory location `DumpMemory` prints to the console, ollydbg shows a JMP instruction at this location:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
00281627   $-/E9 044C0000   JMP CallMessageBoxExA
```

Is this the correct memory-location, or do I have to follow the JMP?

Memory location jump leads to:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
00286230  /$  55            PUSH EBP                                 ; ASM.CallMessageBoxExA(void)
00286231  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
00286233  |.  81EC C0000000 SUB ESP,0C0
00286239  |.  53            PUSH EBX
0028623A  |.  56            PUSH ESI
0028623B  |.  57            PUSH EDI
0028623C  |.  8DBD 40FFFFFF LEA EDI,[EBP-0C0]
00286242  |.  B9 30000000   MOV ECX,30
00286247  |.  B8 CCCCCCCC   MOV EAX,CCCCCCCC
0028624C  |.  F3:AB         REP STOS DWORD PTR ES:[EDI]
0028624E  |.  C705 A8562900 MOV DWORD PTR DS:[message],OFFSET 00291D ; ASCII "ManualMessageBoxExA"
00286258  |.  C705 AC562900 MOV DWORD PTR DS:[caption],OFFSET 00291D ; ASCII "Caption"
00286262  |.  8BF4          MOV ESI,ESP
00286264  |.  68 041E2900   PUSH OFFSET 00291E04                     ; ASCII "MessageBoxExA"
00286269  |.  8BFC          MOV EDI,ESP
0028626B  |.  68 D01D2900   PUSH OFFSET 00291DD0                     ; /ModuleName = "User32.dll"
00286270  |.  FF15 00602900 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.GetModuleH ; \KERNEL32.GetModuleHandleW
00286276  |.  3BFC          CMP EDI,ESP
00286278  |.  E8 5BB2FFFF   CALL 002814D8                            ; [_RTC_CheckEsp
0028627D  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; |hModule
0028627E  |.  FF15 04602900 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.GetProcAdd ; \KERNEL32.GetProcAddress
00286284  |.  3BF4          CMP ESI,ESP
00286286  |.  E8 4DB2FFFF   CALL 002814D8                            ; [_RTC_CheckEsp
0028628B  |.  A3 B0562900   MOV DWORD PTR DS:[pAddr],EAX
00286290  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0
00286292  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0
00286294  |.  FF35 AC562900 PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[caption]
0028629A  |.  FF35 A8562900 PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[message]
002862A0  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0
002862A2  |.  A1 B0562900   MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[pAddr]
002862A7  |.  FFD0          CALL EAX
002862A9  |.  5F            POP EDI
002862AA  |.  5E            POP ESI
002862AB  |.  5B            POP EBX
002862AC  |.  81C4 C0000000 ADD ESP,0C0
002862B2  |.  3BEC          CMP EBP,ESP
002862B4  |.  E8 1FB2FFFF   CALL 002814D8                            ; [_RTC_CheckEsp
002862B9  |.  8BE5          MOV ESP,EBP
002862BB  |.  5D            POP EBP
002862BC  \.  C3            RETN
```

Pointing the dummy function at the byte array:

```
void(*func_ptr)();
func_ptr = (void(*)()) &foo[0]; // make function point to foo[]
(*func_ptr)(); // Call the function
```

Is this the correct way to make the dummy function point to the byte array?

At which point is the function's end reached? Should I simply check for the different return opcodes (C3 -> return near to caller, CB -> return far to caller, ...)?

PS:
A simple (e.g. not very elaborate) solution is preferred as I am new to C++.

Edit: I want to achieve this in a Windows environment.

Comment: [This is not possible in any portable way.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture)  If you want platform-specific advice (it looks like Windows), then specify the platform.

Comment: I would recommend developing your C++ skills with something much less complicated.

Comment: What you are looking to do is a *VERY* powerful thing which is used by a handful of developers in the world (mostly those writing JIT runtimes for languages).  As a point of reference, in my own circle, as a C++ developer of 10 years, I am the only one I personally know who has ever attempted it.

Comment: I am very curious (I am sure others are too) as to what you are trying to do. Are you trying to hook things? if so there are many commercial and free tools for doing that type of thing

Comment: Actually, I am not trying to accomplish anything. I came up with this while thinking about self-modifying code. The problem is much harder than anticipated and I am not able to solve it with my current c++ abilitys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the "copied" function on a block of memory allocated using `VirtualAllocEx`.  On modern OSs, there is a bit on each page which declares whether its contents are executable or not.  This is used to minimize the damage of buffer overruns.  By default, your memory is not executable.  If you use `VirtualAllocEx` with the `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` protection mode, you'll be able to write to a block of memory and then execute from it.

As for your question of "when do you reach the end of a function," that is actually not answerable.  There are common patterns you can look for, but x86 lacks any way of identifying the "end" of a function.

Comment: Also make sure to check the alignment of your data when you try to execute it.  I do not remember offhand if x86 has any alignment requirements on its opcodes, but if it does, you have to ensure they are accounted for.

Comment: And then you also have to apply fixups due to code motion. And detect jump tables and fix them up too. This quickly turns into the Halting Problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to follow the jump. When you follow the jump, the code you're seeing matches what you compiled above.

Also, your DumpMemory is using the address of pAddressIn. Your function is being passed a variable called pAddress. Either this is a typo, or you're referencing a variable declared somewhere else. I assume you meant to use pAddress.

The memory you allocate may need special privilege to be allowed to run. As is, the memory you allocate with the raw function data will be marked as "data". "Data Execution Prevention" may stop this depending on your environment.

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo.